# Invert scrolling for only trackpad, Bootcamp

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac, touchpad, boot-camp

I installed Windows on my MacBook Air using Bootcamp and now I want to invert the scrolling direction for only the trackpad (not for regular mice).

I've tried opening regedit (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\VID_???\VID_???\Device Parameters), but I don't know which device is the trackpad. How do I check which device is the trackpad?

I'm using Windows 10 on a MBA 11" 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it in Device Manager:

1. Press **Win+R** key.
2. Type *devmgmt.msc* and press **Enter**.
3. Look for **Mice and other pointing devices**.
4. There should be an entry for your trackpad. Open it.
5. On the **Details** tab, select **Hardware Ids** property.

There should be a value that matches the one in registry.